Exception: model is not available
I'm getting a Model is not available error message with z3 using symbolic execution model.
The initial code has v1 and v2 added and it works but once I substitute v1 and v2 values, I get a model is not available error
I checked the other posts but couldn't get an answer to it from those.
enter SEED = 682466241
prng = RNG(SEED)
v1 = prng.next(26)
v2 = prng.next(26)
print(SEED, v1, v2)

v1 = 57508594
v2 = 29407552
s = Solver()
s.add(seed >= 0)
s.add(seed <= 0xFFFFFFFF)
s.add(RNG(seed).next(26) == v1)
s.add(RNG(seed).next2(26) == v2)
s.check()
#print(s.check())
#print(s.model())
m = s.model()
print("Seed is: ", m[seed])

prng = RNG(int(str(m[seed])))
prng.next(26)
prng.next(26)
v3 = prng.next(26)
print("V3 is:", v3)

I got the code from this link and it was used in this video but when I try it I get a model is not available error message.
Any help resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

we can't help you if it's not your code. ask the authors

Thanks for the response. I asked him but got no response. You can see my question on his page. I think helping me should be considered like helping an engineer that got hired to a company to work on a code that the creator has left the company or trying to plugin a code from online to an existing project but having some difficulties doing so. Both should be considered as I'm trying to learn and I made some efforts but they weren't successful.

The problem is with these two lines:
v1 = 57508594
v2 = 29407552

If you look at the original web-page you cited, they don't have these assignments. Essentially, you changed the value of v1 and v2 (which is fine), and then z3 told you that these are not viable values. That is, if you start with the code:
SEED = 682466241
prng = RNG(SEED)

and have:
s.add(RNG(seed).next(26) == v1)
s.add(RNG(seed).next2(26) == v2)

then v1 and v2 end up being different values. This is a conflict. Because you are essentially saying v1 as calculated by RNG(seed).next(26) must be 57508594, but actually that computation results in 14325532, and the constraint 57508594 == 14325532 is unsatisfiable. (Since these numbers are not equal to each other.) Thus, z3 ends up telling you unsat, i.e., your constraints are unsatisfiable; and thus there is no model.
You should remove the assignments to v1 or v2 to get a working program. Or, perhaps, remove the assignment to SEED to start with, so z3 can "reverse-calculate" what it must be. (This doesn't mean it will be easy to do so.) But of course it all depends on what exactly you're trying to do.
In general, using an SMT solver to "reverse-engineer" some sort of a cryptographic algorithm is a futile attempt. (Unless the underlying algorithm is really simple; i.e., not cryptographically strong.) But then again, without knowing your goal, it's hard to opine.

Thanks for your replay. So I tried the following based on your response, I removed the seed but still got an "Unsat" error of model is not available. Okay so my goal is to try in predict the third iteration of the algorithm. The user gets a text-box and is asked to enter a number, the number entered by the user is compared with the result of the algorithm RNG(seed).next(26). If its the same then its a win. The goal of using z3 is for the user to be able to enter 2 random numbers as input and use z3 to guess the third number for RNG(seed).next(26)

I assume what you did was keep seed as a symbolic variable, and set v1 and v2 as before. And you got unsat as the result from the call to check? If that's the case, this just means that there is NO seed value that such that your PRNG will produce the v1/v2 values as you've given. This isn't surprising, since PRNG is a deterministic algorithm and apparently whatever v1 value you specified causes seed to be constrained in a way that v2 produced can never be what you ask it to be. Experiment by removing the assignment to either v1 or v2 as well.

You would never believe this but the code finally worked exactly as it was without changing it. I got the code in the video and it was exactly the same as the one I had. So I re-ran it again for the 100th time and it worked. I'll be brushing up on my knowledge on symbolic execution to have a stronger grasp of things. Many thanks for the help to resolve this.

Something must’ve changed. If you get unsat and then sat for the same problem in different runs, then it’s a bug in z3. You should isolate it and repot to developers.

You are right but I did exactly the same thing and kept getting the same error message. The thing is that now that it's working, I can't reproduce the error message any longer. I describe the error and the experience but can't reproduce it. The only thing I can think about is that it may be related to the computer settings or variables because I tried to install docker which the guy in the video had but I couldn't complete the installation successfully.
